# Ubuntu 11.10 LAMP install Apache /var/www/ access denied

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, lamp

Ok I installed Apache2, PHP5, MySql, phpMyAdmin, your standard lamp stack onto my freshly installed Ubuntu 11.10 amd64 desktop edition. All seems to be working properly however unless I go through the terminal and nano as root the index.html thats the server default place holder. I can't do anything else. I have a site I want to essentially drop in there for dev purposes and I can't cause I am getting permission denied errors. Any idea's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo su -

mkdir /vwr/www/somedir

chwon youruser:yourgroup /var/wwwsomedir
```